# MongoDB bulkWrite multiple updateOne vs updateMany

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I have cases where I build bulkWrite operations where some documents have the same `update` object, is there any performance benefit to merging the filters and send one `updateMany` with those filters instead of multiple `updateOne`s in the same `bulkWrite`?

It's obviously better to use `updateMany` over multiple `updateOne`s when using the normal methods, but with bulkWrite, since it's a single command, are there any significant gains of preferring one over the other?

**Example:**

I have 200k documents that I need to update, I have 10 total unique `status` field for all 200K documents, so my options are:

**Solutions:**

**A)** Send one single bulkWrite with 10 `updateMany` operations, and each one of those operations will affect 20K documents.

**B)** Send one single bulkWrite with 200K `updateOne` each operations holding its filter and `status`.

As @AlexBlex noted, I have to look out for accidentally updating more than one document with the same filter, in my case I use `_id` as my filter, so accidentally updating other documents is not a concern in my case, but is definitely something to look out for when considering the `updateMany` option.

Thanks @AlexBlex.

Comment: Update one and update many are different operations. One is not a direct substitute for the other.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if we're using a unique field such as `_id` in the filter, they should substitute each other, correct?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Using `updateMany` is at least twice faster, but might accidentally update more documents than you intended, keep reading to learn how to avoid this and gain the performance benefits.

**Long answer:**

We ran the following experiment to know the answer for that, the following are the steps:

1. Create a *bankaccounts* mongodb collection, each document contains only one field (balance).
2. Insert 1 million documents into the *bankaccounts* collection.
3. Randomize the order in memory of all 1 million documents to avoid any possible optimizations from the database using ids that are inserted in the same sequence, simulating a real-world scenario.
4. Build write operations for bulkWrite from the documents with a random number between 0 and 100.
5. Execute the bulkWrite.
6. Log the time the bulkWrite took.

Now, the experiment lies in the 4th step.

In one variation of the experiment we build an array consisting of 1 million `updateOne` operations, each `updateOne` has `filter` for a single document, and its respective `update object.

In the second variation, we build 100 `updateMany` operations, each including `filter` for 10K documents ids, and their respective `update`.

**Results:**
`updateMany` with multiple documents ids is 243% faster than multiple `updateOne`s, this can not be used everywhere though, **please read "The risk" section to learn when it should be used**.

**Details:**
We ran the script 5 times for each variation, the detailed results are as follows:
With updateOne: 51.28 seconds on average.
With updateMany: 21.04 seconds on average.

**The risk:**
As many people have already pointed out, `updateMany` is not a direct substitute to `updateOne`, since it can incorrectly update multiple documents when our intention was to really update only one document.
This approach is only valid when you're using a field that is unique such as `_id` or any other field that is unique, if the filter is depending on fields that are not unique, multiple documents will be updated and the results will not be equivalent.

**65831219.js**

```js
// 65831219.js
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const DOCUMENTS_COUNT = 1_000_000;
const UPDATE_MANY_OPERATIONS_COUNT = 100;
const MINIMUM_BALANCE = 0;
const MAXIMUM_BALANCE = 100;
const SAMPLES_COUNT = 10;

const bankAccountSchema = new Schema({
  balance: { type: Number }
});

const BankAccount = mongoose.model('BankAccount', bankAccountSchema);

mainRunner().catch(console.error);

async function mainRunner () {
  for (let i = 0; i < SAMPLES_COUNT; i++) {
    await runOneCycle(buildUpdateManyWriteOperations).catch(console.error);
    await runOneCycle(buildUpdateOneWriteOperations).catch(console.error);
    console.log('-'.repeat(80));
  }
  process.exit(0);
}

/**
 *
 * @param {buildUpdateManyWriteOperations|buildUpdateOneWriteOperations} buildBulkWrite
 */
async function runOneCycle (buildBulkWrite) {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

  const { accounts } = await createAccounts({ accountsCount: DOCUMENTS_COUNT });

  const { writeOperations } = buildBulkWrite({ accounts });

  const writeStartedAt = Date.now();

  await BankAccount.bulkWrite(writeOperations);

  const writeEndedAt = Date.now();

  console.log(`Write operations took ${(writeEndedAt - writeStartedAt) / 1000} seconds with \`${buildBulkWrite.name}\`.`);
}



async function createAccounts ({ accountsCount }) {
  const rawAccounts = Array.from({ length: accountsCount }, () => ({ balance: getRandomInteger(MINIMUM_BALANCE, MAXIMUM_BALANCE) }));
  const accounts = await BankAccount.insertMany(rawAccounts);

  return { accounts };
}

function buildUpdateOneWriteOperations ({ accounts }) {
  const writeOperations = shuffleArray(accounts).map((account) => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: account._id },
      update: { balance: getRandomInteger(MINIMUM_BALANCE, MAXIMUM_BALANCE) }
    }
  }));

  return { writeOperations };
}

function buildUpdateManyWriteOperations ({ accounts }) {
  shuffleArray(accounts);
  const accountsChunks = chunkArray(accounts, accounts.length / UPDATE_MANY_OPERATIONS_COUNT);
  const writeOperations = accountsChunks.map((accountsChunk) => ({
    updateMany: {
      filter: { _id: { $in: accountsChunk.map(account => account._id) } },
      update: { balance: getRandomInteger(MINIMUM_BALANCE, MAXIMUM_BALANCE) }
    }
  }));

  return { writeOperations };
}


function getRandomInteger (min = 0, max = 1) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

function shuffleArray (array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length;
  let temporaryValue;
  let randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function chunkArray (array, sizeOfTheChunkedArray) {
  const chunked = [];

  for (const element of array) {
    const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];

    if (!last || last.length === sizeOfTheChunkedArray) {
      chunked.push([element]);
    } else {
      last.push(element);
    }
  }
  return chunked;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ node 65831219.js
Write operations took 20.803 seconds with `buildUpdateManyWriteOperations`.
Write operations took 50.84 seconds with `buildUpdateOneWriteOperations`.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tests were run using **MongoDB version** 4.0.4.

Comment: Right. Reducing the number of operations improves performance.

Comment: Was this test performed using ordered or unordered BulkWriteOptions for BulkWrite? Using unordered BulkWrite option allows for the writes to be executed in parallel.

Comment: @Gestalt that's a good question, the test was performed with `ordered: true` which is the default from Mongoose (mongo driver?)
This was a few years ago, Mongo and Mongoose have released a few versions after that. Feel free to run the experiment and I can modify my answer to reflect your findings.

Answer (score 5):

At high level, if you have same update object, then you can do `updateMany` rather than `bulkWrite`

Reason:

`bulkWrite` is designed to send multiple different commands to the server as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods)

If you have same update object, `updateMany` is best suited.

Performance:

If you have 10k update commands in bulkWrite, it will be executed batch manner internally. It may impact on the execution time

Exact lines from the reference about batching:

> Each group of operations can have at most 1000 operations. If a group exceeds this limit, MongoDB will divide the group into smaller groups of 1000 or less. For example, if the bulk operations list consists of 2000 insert operations, MongoDB creates 2 groups, each with 1000 operations.

Thanks @Alex

Comment: I see. My use-case here is that I have 100K documents, each 10K of which share the same update object, therefore a bulkWrite seems like my best option here. My question is whether 10 `updateMany` * 10K ids in the filter is (significantly?) better than 100K `updateOne`s or not.

Comment: Obviously 10 updateMany in a bulkWrite is the best option, don't forget Network round trip time and internal batching.

Comment: What may be obvious to you is not obvious to everyone. Also, I am comparing
10 * 10K updateMany in a single bulkWrite, to 100k updateOne in a single bulkWrite, it should be a single network roundtrip in both cases, correct?

Comment: It worth mention that bulk operation is limited by 1000 operations per batch https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/ Sending 10k updates in a single bulk update results with 10 "commands".  Another **very** important thing to keep in mind is the filter. It may match more documents in updateMany then you expect. It is highly advisable to OP to post examples of the documents and queries for community to validate.

Comment: @AlexBlex
Ah, yes, this is a very valid concern. In my use-case, I filter only with `_id`, so this is not an issue for this specific case. But it's something that people should be looking out for.

Comment: @Hafez, about the obvious part - it seems you understand that there is no magic in the bulk writes and the sole purpose it to reduce stress on the wire, not on the database. Now if you think about he DB itself - it's where updateOne vs updateMany differs a lot. 100k x 1 _id updates will require 100k index look-ups while 10 x 10k _ids updates will do only 10 look-ups. The later is more efficient. My only concern is the filter of 10k ids is gonna be huge. Does it actually work?

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I have been running an experiment for the past hour, and the results show 2.5x performance gain for `updateMany` over `updateOne`.

I'll be posting the results in detail, as well as the experiment steps for people to fiddle around with.