# mongoDB update collection documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, meteor

I have an update request and that request should update the existing data in my database like the flowing example

existing data => `[{_id:"abnc214124",name:"mustafa",age:12,etc...}, {_id:"abnc21412432",name:"mustafa1",age:32,etc...}, {_id:"abnc214124123",name:"mustafa3",age:52,etc...} etc... ]`

new Data => `[{_id:"abnc214124",name:"mustafaxxx",age:12,etc...}, {_id:"abnc21412432",name:"mustafa1",age:35,etc...}, {_id:"abnc214124123",name:"mustafa3",age:20,etc...} etc... ]`
the updated fields :
in the first document name
second age
third age
what is the best way to update the existing data without affect the old fields (not modified fields)
BTW

I tried to loop through documents and check the fields then update them but this will cause long response time and to solve this I used multithread on NodeJS and now I need better solution

Comment: Not quite clear to me exactly what you're asking here, are you trying to update multiple documents in different ways at once or is it just two separate examples of updates you want to perform?

Comment: i am trying to update multiple
the first one is what i have in database
the second one what cam from api
and i should update the existing one

Comment: I am marginally familiar with MongoDB, so please take this suggestion with some caution. Have you considered using [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)? As to how it compares with multiple `updateMany()`, please see [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831219) and the related answers.

Answer (score 1):

To Update the multiple documents of a collection. you can use **updateMany()**

This is the example of **updateMany()**

```js
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
      multi: true
   }
)
```

In Above example:

**filter** parameter specifies which documents to update

**update** parameter specifies the update to be performed

Comment: Yes that's right but if you notice i need a mongoDB function accept array of object's and doing thing like sync between two arrays